# how to fix Cordova build error on gradle?

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, gradle, compilation

Hi everyone I am sorry if I dont know how to explain my problems.
So I am new on cordova so after finish with my project. I have problem with building.
after command **"cordova build android"** it show me build failed in 2s after that I have tried  command **" cordova run android "** but I got the same problem
please if anyone could help me it will a greet helps thanks you[this is the first windows terminal output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loCWp.png)]
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TdlF.png)]

After it I try to compile  with android studio but I already fail it show me error sync and many more incomprehensible [help](/questions/tagged/help)

Comment: run the command cordova build android --verbose 

you will see additional and actual problems just above build fails. Post them on here and I will try to help

Comment: It kinda looks like you have the sdk path issue... but please share a long screenshot after running cordova build android --verbose